# How to mock request a parameterised resource in liberator?

Tags: clojure, liberator

How can I mock a request to a parameterised liberator resource? Here's my code:

```
(defresource lookup [id]
  :available-media-types  ["application/json"]
  :allowed-methods        [:get]
  :handle-ok              #(lookup-event id))

(event/lookup (ring.mock.request/request :get "/event/1" ))
```

I just get a function back instead of response. Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this is the correct way to do it.

```
((event/lookup 1) (ring.mock.request/request :get "/event/1" ))
```